# Persistent HTTPS Connections in Python

Tags: python, http, real-time, persistent

I want to make an HTTPS request to a real-time stream and keep the connection open so that I can keep reading content from it and processing it.

I want to write the script in python. I am unsure how to keep the connection open in my script. I have tested the endpoint with curl which keeps the connection open successfully. But how do I do it in Python. Currently, I have the following code:

```
c = httplib.HTTPSConnection('userstream.twitter.com')
c.request("GET", "/2/user.json?" + req.to_postdata())
response = c.getresponse()
```

Where do I go from here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your real-time stream is delivered as one endless HTTP GET response, yes?  If so, you could just use python's built-in [urllib2.urlopen()](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html).  It returns a file-like object, from which you can read as much as you want until the server hangs up on you.

```
f=urllib2.urlopen('https://encrypted.google.com/')
while True:
    data = f.read(100)
    print(data)
```

Keep in mind that although urllib2 speaks https, it doesn't validate server certificates, so you might want to try and add-on package like [pycurl](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycurl/) or [urlgrabber](http://urlgrabber.baseurl.org/) for better security.  (I'm not sure if urlgrabber supports https.)

Answer (score 1):

Connection keep-alive features are not available in any of the python standard libraries for https.  The most mature option is probably [`urllib3`](http://code.google.com/p/urllib3/)

Comment: this is false. urllib2 from stdlib doesn't support persistent connections but [httplib does support it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9781027/4279). Though urllib3 or [requests (built on top of urllib3)](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) are not bad options if you can use 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

[httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) supports this. (I'd have thought this the most mature option, didn't know urllib3 yet, so TokenMacGuy may still be right)

EDIT: while httplib2 does support persistent connections, I don't think you can really consume streams with it (ie. one long response vs. multiple requests over the same connection), which I now realise you may need.