# Persistence of urllib.request connections to a HTTP server

Tags: python, http, python-3.x

I want to do some performance testing on one of our web servers, to see how the server handles a lot of persistent connections. Unfortunately, I'm not terribly familiar with HTTP  and web testing. Here's the Python code I've got for this so far:

```
import http.client
import argparse
import threading


def make_http_connection():
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(options.server, timeout=30)
    conn.connect()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument("num", type=int, help="Number of connections to make (integer)")
    parser.add_argument("server", type=str, help="Server and port to connect to. Do not prepend \'http://\' for this")

    options = parser.parse_args()

    for n in range(options.num):
        connThread = threading.Thread(target = make_http_connection, args = ())
        connThread.daemon = True
        connThread.start()

    while True:
        try:
            pass
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
```

My main question is this: *How do I keep these connections alive?* I've set a long timeout, but that's a very crude method and I'm not even sure it affects the connection. Would simply requesting a byte or two every once in a while do it?

(Also, on an unrelated note, is there a better procedure for waiting for a keyboard interrupt than the ugly `while True:` block at the end of my code?)

Comment: What do you mean by "persistent connections"?  Normal activity for your server will be for a client to connect, and the server to send it's response and close the connection.

Comment: @jjm Specifically connections which are kept alive using the "Connection: Keep-Alive" header ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`urllib.request` doesn't support persistent connections. There is `'Connection: close'` hardcoded in the code. But `http.client` partially supports persistent connections (including legacy http/1.0 `keep-alive`). So the question title might be misleading.

---

> I want to do some performance testing on one of our web servers, to see how the server handles a lot of persistent connections. Unfortunately, I'm not terribly familiar with HTTP and web testing.

You could use an existing http testing tools such as [slowloris](http://ha.ckers.org/slowloris/), httperf instead of writing one yourself.

---

> How do I keep these connections alive?

To close http/1.1 connection a client should explicitly specify `Connection: close` header otherwise the connection is considered persistent by the server (though it may close it at any moment and [`http.client` won't know about it](http://bugs.python.org/issue3566) until it tries to read/write to the connection).

`conn.connect()` returns almost immediately and your thread ends. To force each thread to maintain an http connection to the server you could:

```
import time

def make_http_connection(*args, **kwargs):
    while True: # make new http connections
        h = http.client.HTTPConnection(*args, **kwargs)
        while True: # make multiple requests using a single connection
            try:
                h.request('GET', '/') # send request; make conn. on the first run
                response = h.getresponse()
                while True: # read response slooowly
                    b = response.read(1) # read 1 byte
                    if not b:
                       break
                    time.sleep(60) # wait a minute before reading next byte
                    #note: the whole minute might pass before we notice that 
                    #  the server has closed the connection already
            except Exception:
                break # make new connection on any error
```

Note: if the server returns `'Connection: close'` then there is a single request per connection.

---

> (Also, on an unrelated note, is there a better procedure for waiting for a keyboard interrupt than the ugly while True: block at the end of my code?)

To wait until all threads finish or `KeyboardInterrupt` happens you could:

```
while threads:
    try:
        for t in threads[:]: # enumerate threads
            t.join(.1) # timeout 0.1 seconds
            if not t.is_alive():
               threads.remove(t)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Or something like this:

```
while threading.active_count() > 1:
    try:
        main_thread = threading.current_thread()
        for t in threading.enumerate(): # enumerate all alive threads
            if t is not main_thread:
               t.join(.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

The later might not work for various reasons e.g., if there are dummy threads such as threads that started in C extensions without using `threading` module.

[concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) provides a higher abstraction level than `threading` module and it can hide some complexity.

Instead of thread per connection model you could open multiple connections concurrently in a single thread e.g., using `requests.async` or `gevent` directly.

Comment: So much help contained within this answer. Thanks, J.F.!

Comment: @Kudzu: I've updated the question to mention `ThreadPoolExecutor`, `requests.async` that provide higher-level interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

If *a lot* is really **a lot** then you probably want use asynchronous io not threads.

[requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) + [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) = [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests)

GRequests allows you to use Requests with Gevent to make asynchronous HTTP Requests easily.

```
import grequests

urls = [
    'http://www.heroku.com',
    'http://tablib.org',
    'http://httpbin.org',
    'http://python-requests.org',
    'http://kennethreitz.com'
]

requests = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
responses = grequests.map(requests)
```

Requests [support](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#keep-alive) persistent HTTP connections.

Comment: note: "a lot" might lead to [Too many open files](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/239)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going a bit outside my knowledge-base here, but I would assume that your thread finnishes when the function make_http_connection() completes. That is if you want them all you would want to include a:

```
while condition:
    pass
```

At the end of the function. I suppose you want them all to become active at the same time? Then let the function modify a global variable and use the condition to test this value against options.num so that the processes will wait until all of them are running before they start terminating.

Side-question, guessing what you're aiming at here, can't you just ask threading to count how many live threads you have and keep running until there's none left?

```
threading.active_count()
```

This here discusses reading keyboard, if that is what you need:

[Polling the keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292095/polling-the-keyboard-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You really should be using a benchmark tool like [Funkload](http://funkload.nuxeo.org/) to do that. If you don't have experience with HTTP, trying to do a performance test from the scratch like that will certainly lead to bad results.