# How do I respond directly to a post request using urllib3 and app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urllib3

I am trying to have a persistent connection to a third party using app engine. Specifically I am hooking into a real time bidding environment where I need to respond in under 100ms, and thus a persistent connection greatly accelerates the process.

In order to do this I am attempting to use urllib3 (if there is a better way please tell me)
When my request handler's post method gets called, I want to write back out to the calling url keeping the connection open. I understand how to open a request with urllib3, but how do I persist the connection that was created when the post method on the handler was called.

At the moment I am trying:

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('POST', self.request.url, fields={"foo":"bar"})
```

But I fear I am opening an entirely new connection doing this.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: possible duplicate of [Persistence of urllib.request connections to a HTTP server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772854/persistence-of-urllib-request-connections-to-a-http-server)

Comment: Close voters: not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to achieve persistent connection to a server with AppEngine, by design every request on the app engine closes after finish sending.

> The **URL Fetch service does not support persistent HTTP connections**.
>   When the app accesses response data using the URLConnection object,
>   App Engine calls the URL Fetch service to complete the request. After
>   the response data has been accessed, the request data cannot be
>   modified.
>
> The app cannot set explicit connection timeouts for the request.

Comment: Isn't Url Fetch used only for out going? I want to persist the incoming connection and write back out on the same connection, which I thought I could use urllib3 for the outgoing.

Comment: Its not possible for the same reason, by the time you get the request the connection is disconnected.