# Does python httplib allow persistent connection?

Tags: python, httplib, persistent-connection

As I read the sample code, I first need to open and connection

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(server)
```

and then I can send multiple requests without making a new connection:

```
 conn.request(...)
```

So does it mean that I have a persistent connection ? Or httplib will make a new connection every request ? How to ensure a persistent connection with httplib ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Persistent HTTPS Connections in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198552/persistent-https-connections-in-python)

Comment: related: [Persistence of urllib.request connections to a HTTP server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772854/persistence-of-urllib-request-connections-to-a-http-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Your best bet is [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the connection is persistent, assuming the server supports it.  In the [first example](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#examples), you can verify that the connection sock attribute is reused.  Note the response has to be closed, e.g. read(), each time as well.